# Vergangenheitsform von (wie ich glaube) Konjunktiv

Tags: grammaticality, subjunctive

Ich möchte folgenden Text anpassen und bin mir absolut nicht sicher, welche Form ich für das, was ich aussagen möchte, benutzen muss:

> Samstagskindern wurden bis in frühe Mittelalter magische Kräfte zugeschrieben, mit denen sie beispielsweise dämonische Wesen erkennen und böse Kräfte bekämpfen konnten.

So weit, so gut. Allerdings ist es ja nicht tatsächlich so, dass diese Kinder „dämonische Wesen erkennen und böse Kräfte bekämpfen konnten“. Das heißt, ich würde es gerne in eine Art Konjuktiv verwandeln, am Besten in einer Art wie „Die Kinder sollen angeblich etwas gekonnt haben“.

Jedoch hört sich

> Samstagskindern wurden bis in frühe Mittelalter magische Kräfte zugeschrieben, mit denen sie beispielsweise dämonische Wesen erkennen und böse Kräfte bekämpfen gekonnt haben sollen.

immer noch falsch an.

Comment: Wie wär's mit _vermeintlich_?

Comment: Für mich klingt der Satz richtig.

Comment: *… bekämpfen könnten.* Falls du auf die Vergangenheit Wert legst: *… hätten bekämpfen können.* Ich halte das allerdings für unwesentlich, da es sich ohnehin nicht um Fakten handelt.

Comment: ... *hätten* dämonische Wesen *erkennen* und böse Kräfte *bekämpfen können*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich geb mal einigen Ballast weg, der bei der Analyse nur stört. Was ich jetzt weglasse, kann man ja später wieder hinzufügen. Im Wesentlichen lauten die beiden Sätze aus der Frage wie folgt:

**--A--**

1. > Kindern wurden Kräfte zugeschrieben, mit denen sie Wesen erkennen konnten.
2. > Kindern wurden Kräfte zugeschrieben, mit denen sie Wesen erkennen gekonnt haben sollen.

Nach dem Komma steht ein Relativsatz, der das Nomen *»Kräfte«* näher beschreibt und der mit *»mit denen«* eingeleitet wird. Daraus kann man einen ganz normalen Aussagesatz machen, indem man die Einleitung weglässt und das finite Verb, das jetzt am Ende des Satzes steht, an Position 2 des neuen Satzes stellt. Dann erhält man diese beiden Sätze:

**--B--**

1. > Sie konnten Wesen erkennen.
2. > Sie sollen Wesen erkennen gekonnt haben.

Einfacher wäre es natürlich ohne dem Modalverb *können*, denn dann hätten wir:

**--C--**

1. > Sie erkannten Wesen.
2. > Sie sollen Wesen erkannt haben.

Nr. 1 ist ganz klar ein Satz im Modus Indikativ, die Zeitform ist Präteritum.

In Nr. 2 gibt es aber keinen Konjunktiv. Auch hier liegt ein Indikativ vor, allerdings haben wir hier gleich drei Verben, nämlich ein Vollverb (*erkannt*), ein Hilfsverb (*haben*) und ein Modalverb (*sollen*).

Diese Kombination wird zur Wiedergabe einer Behauptung verwendet, von der sich der Sprecher distanziert.

Wirklich schwierig wird es, wenn man jetzt noch das Modalverb *»können«* hinzugeben will. Im Fall 1 ist das kein Problem, denn es ist dann das einzige Modalverb im Satz:

**--D--**

1. > Sie konnten Wesen erkennen.

Bei 2 mache ich vorher noch einen weiteren Vereinfachungsschritt:

2. > Sie sollen Wesen erkennen.

Das kann jetzt nicht nur als eine Behauptung über einen gegenwärtigen Vorgang interpretiert werden, sondern auch als eine Aufforderung. Diese Doppeldeutigkeit soll uns aber an dieser Stelle nicht weiter stören. Jedenfalls kann man hier leicht das zweite Modalverb einfügen:

2. > Sie sollen Wesen erkennen können.

Und jetzt wieder zurück ins Perfekt:

2. > Sie sollen Wesen erkannt haben können.

Wie man sieht, stimmt B1 mit D1 überein, aber B2 nicht mit D2. Das liegt daran, dass B2 falsch ist.

Machen wir daraus wieder Relativsätze. Das heißt: Das Verb, das jetzt an Position 2 steht, kommt ans Ende des Satzes, und davor kommt die Einleitung *»mit denen*, und davor der Hauptsatz:

**--E--**

1. > Kindern wurden Kräfte zugeschrieben, mit denen sie Wesen erkennen konnten.
2. > Kindern wurden Kräfte zugeschrieben, mit denen sie Wesen erkannt haben können sollen.

Und jetzt mit dem ganzen Zierrat:

**--F--**

1. > Samstagskindern wurden bis in frühe Mittelalter magische Kräfte zugeschrieben, mit denen sie beispielsweise dämonische Wesen erkennen und böse Kräfte bekämpfen konnten.
2. > Samstagskindern wurden bis in frühe Mittelalter magische Kräfte zugeschrieben, mit denen sie beispielsweise dämonische Wesen erkannt und böse Kräfte bekämpft  haben können sollen.

---

Das ist jetzt zwar grammatisch korrekt,

### ABER:

Der Satz #2 holpert trotzdem arg, und der Grund dafür sind die vier Verben am Ende des Satzes, von denen zwei Modalverben sind. Die Lösung aus diesem Dilemma ist eine andere Formulierung. Aus *»können«* wird *»in der Lage sein«*, und gleichzeitig fügt man einen »Infintiv mit zu« (hier sogar zweimal) ein. Das ist zwar länger, aber trotzdem geschmeidiger:

2. > Samstagskindern wurden bis in frühe Mittelalter magische Kräfte zugeschrieben, mit denen sie beispielsweise in der Lage gewesen sein sollen, dämonische Wesen zu erkennen und böse Kräfte zu bekämpfen.

Answer (score 1):

Ähnlich wie Hubert, juckt es mich, den Satz umzustellen. Ich ziehe das Verb ans Ende:

- Original:

  > Samstagskindern wurden bis in frühe Mittelalter magische Kräfte zugeschrieben, mit denen sie beispielsweise dämonische Wesen erkennen und böse Kräfte bekämpfen konnten.
- Umstellung:

  > Samstagskindern wurden bis in frühe Mittelalter magische Kräfte, mit denen sie beispielsweise dämonische Wesen erkennen und böse Kräfte bekämpfen konnten, zugeschrieben.

Wie man sieht, beschreibt der Nebensatz die magischen Kräfte näher. Dass diesen Kindern die magischen Kräfte nur zugeschrieben wurden, wird durch das *zugeschrieben* unmissverständlich ausgedrückt. Für ein weiteres Sprachmittel, das auszudrücken, besteht kein Bedarf.

Den Nebensatz könnte man auch weglassen, ohne grammatisch weiter aktiv werden zu müssen:

> Samstagskindern wurden bis in frühe Mittelalter magische Kräfte zugeschrieben.